# passing context to timer android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Inside my class I have timer which counts from 5 sec to 0 sec. I want to start new activity when counting ends. The problem is I dont know which context to put as argument in function.

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayGameActivity extends Activity {

    private Intent i;
    private Game igra;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        }


         new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

             TextView mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 mTextField.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 mTextField.setText("Gotovo!");
                 //here is the problem!
                Intent intent = new Intent( getBaseContext() , TableActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
             }
          }.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass  `PlayGameActivity.this`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent( PlayGameActivity.this , TableActivity.class);
```

Comment: A get warnning again that app has stopped. Is there matter if I have started TableActivity in some of my previous Activities ?